# Windows Client For Cloudera Hadoop Cluster

Tags: cloudera, bigdata

I am trying to find out if I can use Windows Client machines for commissioning jobs running on a Linux Cloudera Cluster.

I currently use Linux clients and would like to run tasks such as spark-submit test.jar which runs a spark job on the cluster and replicate this behavior on windows clients.

If yes, any information about how you can go about doing this would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use `VM linux image` installed on `windows` and access `Hadoop` cluster deployed on Linux.

You can also use `cygwin` otherwise.